# Как создать связанный подзапрос MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблици:

- disciplines: id, name;
- marks: id, s_id, d_id, t_id, value;

Следует создать связанный подзапрос на выборку названия дисциплин, средняя оценка по которым выше 3.
В общем толком мне ничего не расказали, в интернети информации мало, но кое что нашел. Выходит внутрений запрос будет сравнивать каждое из средних значений дисциплин с таблици оценок с 3:

```
SELECT name FROM disciplines 
WHERE 3 < (SELECT AVG(value) FROM marks WHERE marks.d_id = disciplines.id GROUP BY marks.d_id);
```

Запрос вроде правильный (выведен правильный ответ),но я почему-то сомневаюсь. Ответьте пожалуйста,правильный ли он.

Comment: так правильно или нет?

Comment: Ну я бы поменял местами (SELECT AVG(value) FROM marks WHERE marks.d_id = disciplines.id GROUP BY marks.d_id) и < 3, а то как-то не по-людски)))

Comment: @Kryshtop, спасибо,а не посомтрите еще одну мою тему. Если не сочтете это за наглость)

Comment: @Kryshtop, посмотрите пожалуйста. В чем проблема: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/590592/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%85-%d1%89%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-mysql