# Подвох запроса MySQL

Tags: mysql

Есть таблици:

- students: id, name, surname;
- disciplines: id, name;
- marks: id, s_id, d_id, t_id, value.

Необходимо создать связанный подзапрос, который выведет фамилии студентов, которые имеют оценки 3 и 4 одновременно. Сделал так:

```
SELECT id, name, surname FROM students WHERE 3 or 4 IN (SELECT value FROM marks WHERE marks.st_id = students.id GROUP BY marks.st_id);
```

Этот запрос выведет всех студентов, даже тех, которые вообще не имеют оценки.
Если or заменить на and выведет нужного человека. Но разве AND не означает, что должна возникнуть ошибка, ведь значение не может быть одновременно 3 и 4.

скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48450/discussion-on-question-by-muscled-boy---mysql).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, surname
  FROM students S
 WHERE 2=(select count(distinct value) from marks M
           where M.st_id=S.id and M.value IN(3,4)
         )
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48451/discussion-on-answer-by-mike---mysql).